# Groovy @Builder not visible in Java (and eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I am trying to simplify my Java code by the use of groovy. At the moment I am struggling with the use of the @Builder annotation. I have a groovy like the following one….

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder

@Builder
class TheFancyOne {
    String message
}
```

From Java I want to use the builder like…

```
TheFancyOne.builder().message("Hello World!").build();
```

The problem is, that only the getter and setter of the “TheFancyOne” is visible but no builder.

As a side note I am unsing groovy 2.4.5 and Eclipse (Neo with Groovy Eclipse)

--- edit ---
The builder is visible within groovy and it is also in the resulting jar (checked by decompiling). So it seems to be an eclipse plugin issue

Any idea?

Regards,
Thomas

Comment: Is the builder() method visible from a Groovy method in the same file, or is that not there either? (Also, try compiling from the command line, in case it's just an Eclipse issue.)

Comment: Yes it is visible within groovy and I found the builder also in the resulting jar. Therefore it seems to be a Eclipse plugin problem. I will try the code later on IntelliJ.